# How to convert a sas date format into a string format

Tags: format, sas

i have a variable with values like 5600/06.. this is a strig variable but got wrongly imported as date format. how can i change it to string format again?

Thnx in advance...

Comment: Can you paste the code you use, and a sample of the input data.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're using proc import to import this data?

For this sort of "custom" import, you must instead copy the data step used to import the data generated by proc import (it's in the log!) and adjust the relevent field. For example, if sas produces:

```
data result;

infile "<your file>";

input good_variable $ bad_variable date9.;

run;
```

you must change the import to:

```
data result;
infile "<your file>";

input good_variable $100 bad_variable $100;

run;
```

Comment: Assuming you are in the SAS IDE; after you run PROC IMPORT, open a new code window and select "Run->Recall Last Submit".  This will paste the code PROC IMPORT created into the new window.